# Reloading a docker container from another container

Tags: docker, containers, certbot

Good day. My task is to raise a container with Certbot, which will re-issue certificates for other containers. After re-issuing certificates, I need to somehow send a signal to other containers to reload them. Can this be done from a Certbot container?
An approximate algorithm of actions is as follows:

1. Raise the Certbot container with the total Volume.
2. Raise another container and connect its catalog with certificates to the general Volume.
3. Configure certbot to reissue certificates.
4. After re-issuing certificates, send a reboot signal from the container with Certbot to another container.

How can I implement the fourth point?

Answer (score 0):

here's one possibility that i can think of.

- bind volume with the outside host.
- keep a file in that volume inside the container and keep adding some signaling metadata e.g. write cert name alongside timestamp.
- run a script on the host that will read the file and run the appropriate command(s) on behalf of this certbot container.